# What is the most surprising characterization of the Gaussian (normal) distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics, characteristic-function

A standardized Gaussian distribution on $\mathbb{R}$ can be defined by giving explicitly its density: 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$$

or its characteristic function.

As recalled in [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/distributions-other-than-the-normal-where-mean-and-variance-are-independent) question it is also the only distribution for which the sample mean and variance are independent.

What are other surprising alternative characterization of Gaussian measures that you know ? I will accept the most surprising answer

Answer (score 46, accepted):

My personal most surprising is the one about the sample mean and variance, but here is another (maybe) surprising characterization: if $X$ and $Y$ are IID with finite variance with $X+Y$ and $X-Y$ independent, then $X$ and $Y$ are normal.

Intuitively, we can usually identify when variables are not independent with a scatterplot.  So imagine a scatterplot of $(X,Y)$ pairs that looks independent.   Now rotate by 45 degrees and look again: if it **still** looks independent, then the $X$ and $Y$ coordinates individually must be normal (this is all speaking loosely, of course).

To see why the intuitive bit works, take a look at

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos45^{\circ} & -\sin45^{\circ} \newline 
\sin45^{\circ} & \cos45^{\circ} 
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x \newline
y
\end{array}
\right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x-y \newline
x+y
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: Jay - this is basically a re-statement of the mean and variance being independent.  $X+Y$ is a re-scaled mean and $X-Y$ is a rescaled standard deviation.

Comment: @probabilityislogic - I like the intuition of what you said, but I don't think it is exactly a restatement because $X - Y$ isn't exactly a rescaling of the SD: the SD forgets the sign. So independence of mean and SD follows from independence of $X+Y$, $X-Y$ (when $n = 2$), but not the other way around.  That may have been what you meant by "basically".  Anyway, it's good stuff.

Comment: is there connection to Box-Muller transformation ?

Comment: Where can we find proof for this property?

Comment: Can this result be extended for 3 or more variables?

Comment: @Royi this problem appears in Gut's *Probability: A Graduate Course* in the chapter about CLT, although the proof involves only tricky computations with the characteristic functions of the RVs at hand.

Comment: @LeGrandDODOM, I'd be happy to see the proof you mentioned. I now know another proof ([The Levy Cramer Theorem](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=B7Ch-c2G21MC&pg=PA205&dq=cramer+theorem&redir_esc=y&hl=en#v=onepage&q=cramer%20theorem&f=false)).

Comment: @Royi see 16. [here](http://imgur.com/qykHNYg). For (a), note that $2X=(X+Y)+(X-Y)$. For (b) note that $\varphi(2t)\varphi(-2t)=(\varphi(t)\varphi(-t))^4$ which yearns for the substitution $\psi(t)=\varphi(t)\varphi(-t)$ from which you get $\psi(t)=\psi^{2^{2n}}(\frac{t}{2^n})$. If $\varphi(t_0)=0$, then  $\psi(t_0)=0$, hence for all $n$, $\psi(\frac{t_0}{2^n})=0$ and there is a sequence $t_n$ such that $t_n\to 0$ and $\varphi(t_n)=0$ for all $n$, which contradicts continuity of $\varphi$ at $0$. (c) is straighforward [continued]

Comment: For (d), $\gamma(t)=\gamma^{2^n}(\frac{t}{2^n})$. Note that $\varphi(t)=1-\frac{t^2}2+o(t^2)$, hence $\gamma(t)=1+o(t^2)$. Plug this in the previous equality and prove that for fixed $t$, $\lim_n \gamma^{2^n}(\frac{t}{2^n}) = 1$ which implies $\gamma(t)=1$ for all $t$. This means $\varphi$ is real, and the equality in (a) turns into what is asked. Again, prove that $\varphi(t)=\varphi^{2^{2n}}(\frac{t}{2^n})$ and use $\varphi(t)=1-\frac{t^2}2+o(t^2)$ to get $\lim_n \varphi^{2^{2n}}(\frac{t}{2^n}) = e^{-t^2/2}$. Hence $\varphi(t)=e^{-t^2/2}$ and $X$ is normal.

Answer (score 30):

The continuous distribution with fixed variance which maximizes [differential entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy) is the Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 26):

There's an entire book written about this: "Characterizations of the normal probability law", A. M. Mathai & G. Perderzoli.  A brief review in [JASA (Dec. 1978)](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2286313) mentions the following:

> Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent random variables.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i x_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n{b_i x_i}$ are independent, where $a_i b_i \ne 0$, if and only if $X_i$ [are] normally distributed.

Comment: there must be a condition such $<a,b>=0$ missing ? for example if n=2 $a_i=b_i=1$ $X_1+X_2$  and $X_1+X_2$ are not independant.

Comment: @robin good catch.  I've been puzzling over the implicit quantifiers, too.  Unfortunately, all I have access to is that (titillating) quotation from the review, not the book.  It would be fun to find it in a library and browse through it...

Comment: This feels like a generalization of G. Jay Kerns' (currently #1) answer.

Comment: I think you may be looking for the Lukacs & King (1954) paper. [See this answer at math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42115/when-linear-combinations-of-independent-random-variables-are-still-independent/42124#42124) with a link to the aforementioned paper.

Comment: Where this proposition says "where $a_i b_i\ne 0$", does it mean for EVERY set of scalars where $a_i b_i \ne 0$"?  I hate seeing "where" used in place of "for every" or "for some".  "Where" should be used to explain one's notation, as in "where $c$ is the speed of light and $g$ is the gross domestic product", etc.

Comment: @Michael: If $a_1=0$, for instance, then the independence of the two linear combinations tells us nothing at all about $X_1$, so we cannot conclude it is normal. From that I infer that "$a_i b_i\ne 0$" is intended to say that all the coefficients $a_i$ and $b_i$ must be nonzero. The statement still is not correct, however: an orthogonality condition has to be included in the assumptions somewhere.

Comment: @whuber : Conspicuously absent from you comment is anything about whether it means "for every" or "for some" or something else.

Answer (score 21):

[Stein’s Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_lemma) provides a very useful characterization.  $Z$ is standard Gaussian iff 
$$E f’(Z) = E Z f(Z)$$
for all absolutely continuous functions $f$ with $E|f’(Z)| < \infty$.

Answer (score 19):

Gaussian distributions are the only [sum-stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) distributions with finite variance.

Comment: That they are sum stable and that they are the unique ones with finite variance are both forced on us by the CLT.  The interesting part of this assertion is that there exist *other* sum-stable distributions!

Comment: @whuber: indeed! this characterization is a bit contorted, and the other sum-stable distributions are perhaps more curious.

Comment: @whuber actually, I do not see how the CLT implies this fact. It only seems to tell us that _asymptotically_, the sum of normals is normal, not that any finite sum is normally distributed. Or do you have to somehow use Slutsky's theorem as well?

Comment: Adopting the usual standardization, a sum of two normals is the sum of one normal distribution X_0 plus the limiting distribution of a series X_1, X_2, ..., whence the sum is the limiting distribution of X_0, X_1, ..., which by the Lindeberg-Levy CLT is normal.

Answer (score 13):

**Theorem [Herschel-Maxwell]:** Let $Z \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a random vector for which (i) projections into orthogonal subspaces are independent and (ii) the distribution of $Z$ depends only on the length $\|Z\|$. Then $Z$ is normally distributed.

Cited by George Cobb in [*Teaching statistics: Some important tensions*](http://chjs.mat.utfsm.cl/volumes/02/01/Cobb(2011).pdf) (Chilean J. Statistics Vol. 2, No. 1, April 2011) at p. 54.

Cobb uses this characterization as a starting point for deriving the $\chi^2$, $t$, and $F$ distributions, without using Calculus (or much probability theory).

Answer (score 10):

This is not a characterization but a conjecture, which dates back from 1917 and is due to Cantelli:

> If $f$ is a positive function on $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ and $Y$ are $N(0,1)$ independent random variables such that $X+f(X)Y$ is normal, then $f$ is a constant almost everywhere.

Mentioned by Gérard Letac [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37151/what-are-the-big-problems-in-probability-theory/39999#39999).

Comment: it is good that you mention it! I can't figure out the intuition, do you?

Comment: @robin This is what makes this conjecture so special: a completely elementary statement, some obvious approaches which fail miserably (characteristic functions), and one is left with nothing to grasp... By the way, should one bet on the conjecture being true or false? Even that is not obvious (to me).

Comment: If Gérard Letac has not managed to prove it, it could stay an open conjecture for quite a while...!

Comment: @Xi'an: I fully agree, of course. (Didn't know you were roaming in these quarters of the web... Good news that you are.)

Comment: @DidierPiau: thanks!,  I just saw this announcement: <a href="http://www.mathnet.ru/php/seminars.phtml?option_lang=eng&presentid=4082">A counterexample to Cantelli's conjecture</a> given by Victor Kleptsyn at the Dobrushin Mathematics Laboratory Seminar a few weeks ago. But no abstract and no trace of a preprint anywhere.

Comment: @Xi'an Here is a [preprint](http://hal.inria.fr/hal-00666733/) by Victor Kleptsyn and Aline Kurtzmann with a counterexample to the Cantelli conjecture. The construction uses a new tool, which the authors call the Brownian mass transport, and yields a discontinuous function $f$. The authors state that they believe that Cantelli conjecture holds if one asks that $f$ is continuous (theirs is a mixture of two continuous functions).

Answer (score 9):

Let $\eta$ and $\xi$ be two independent random variables with a common symmetric distribution such that

$$ P\left ( \left |\frac{\xi+\eta}{\sqrt{2}}\right | \geq t \right )\leq P(|\xi|\geq t).$$

Then these random variables are gaussian. (Obviously, if the $\xi$ and $\eta$ are centered gaussian, it is true.)

This is the [Bobkov-Houdre Theorem](http://www.math.ethz.ch/EMIS/journals/EJP-ECP/EcpVol1/paper2.pdf)

Answer (score 9):

Suppose one is estimating a location parameter using i.i.d. data $\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. If $\bar{x}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator, then the sampling distribution is Gaussian. According to Jaynes's *Probability Theory: The Logic of Science* pp. 202-4, this was how Gauss originally derived it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this as a characterisation of the normal distribution, so I'm probably missing something. What if we had iid Poisson data and wanted to estimate $\mu$? The MLE is $\bar{x}$ but the sampling distribution of $\bar{x}$ isn't Gaussian - firstly, $\bar{x}$ has to be rational; secondly, if it were Gaussian, so would be $\sum{x_i}$ but that's $\text{Poisson}(n\mu)$.

Comment: The Poisson mean is not a location parameter!

Answer (score 7):

A more particular characterisation of the normal distribution among the class of [infinitely divisible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_%28probability%29) distributions is presented in [Steutel and Van Harn (2004)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0824707249).

> A non-degenerate infinitely divisible random variable $X$ has a normal distribution if and only if it satisfies
>   $$-\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{\log{\mathbb P}(\vert X\vert>x)}{x\log(x)}=\infty.$$

This result characterises the normal distribution in terms of its tail behaviour.

Comment: A short proof of the stated limit goes as follows: If $X$ is standard normal, then $x \mathbb P(X>x)/\varphi(x)\to 1$ as $x\to \infty$, so $\log\mathbb P(X>x)−\log \varphi(x) + \log x \to 0$. But $2 \log \varphi(x) \sim −x^2$ and so the result follows. A rough sketch for the case of the Poisson seems to indicate that the given limit is $\lambda$, but I didn't check that too closely.

Comment: This seems a bit of a cheat to me, because the initial restriction to infinitely divisible distributions is a very strong one.  Thus, the Normal distribution is singled out as lying on the boundary of a relatively tiny space: interesting but not surprising.

Answer (score 6):

In the context of image smoothing (e.g. [scale space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-space_axioms)), the Gaussian is the only rotationally symmetric separable* kernel.

That is, if we require
$$F[x,y]=f[x]f[y]$$
where $[x,y]=r[\cos\theta,\sin\theta]$, then rotational symmetry requires
\begin{align}
F_\theta &= f'[x]f[y]x_\theta+f[x]f'[y]y_\theta \\
 &= -f'[x]f[y]y+f[x]f'[y]x = 0 \\
&\implies \\
\frac{f'[x]}{xf[x]} &= \frac{f'[y]}{yf[y]} = \mathrm{const.}
\end{align}
which is equivalent to $\log\big[f[x]\big]'=cx$.

Requiring that $f[x]$ be a proper [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) then requires the constant be negative and the initial value positive, yielding the Gaussian kernel.

---

*In the context of probability distributions, separable means independent, while in the context of image filtering it allows the 2D convolution to be reduced computationally to two 1D convolutions.

Comment: +1 But doesn't this follow from an immediate application of the [Herschel-Maxwell theorem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24591/919) in 2D?

Comment: @whuber Indeed, somehow I managed to overlook your answer when looking through this thread!

Comment: @whuber Yes. I had not read through this old thread in detail, and was just adding this answer by request.

Comment: @amoeba see also [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29869/the-only-spherical-and-independent-density-is-normal).

Answer (score 3):

Its characteristic function has the same form as its pdf.  I am not sure of another distribution which does that.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21180/fourier-transform-of-distributions/21189#21189) of mine for ways of constructing random variables whose characteristic functions are the same as their pdfs.

Answer (score 3):

Recently Ejsmont [1] published article with new characterization of Gaussian:

Let $(X_1,\dots, X_m,Y) \textrm{ and } (X_{m+1},\dots,X_n,Z)$ be independent  random vectors with all moments, where  $X_i$ are
nondegenerate,  and let statistic $\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i+Y+Z$
have a distribution which depends only on $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$, where $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$ and $1\leq m < n$.  Then $X_i $ are independent and have the same normal distribution with zero means and $cov(X_i,Y)=cov(X_i,Z)=0$ for $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$.

[1]. Ejsmont, Wiktor. "A characterization of the normal distribution by the independence of a pair of random vectors." Statistics & Probability Letters 114 (2016): 1-5.

Comment: That's a delicate and fascinating characterization.  Thank you for improving this thread by sharing it!

Answer (score -1):

The expectation plus minus the standard deviation are the saddle points of the function.

Comment: This is a property of the Normal distribution, to be sure, but it does not *characterize* it, because plenty of other distributions also have this property.