# When are two normally distributed random variables jointly bivariate normal?

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to have a pair of Gaussian random variables for which the joint distribution is not Gaussian?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d)

For our upcoming exam we had to calculate the joint density of two normally distributed random variables a few times.

Say $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(2,3)$.

We just assumed that $Z=(X,Y)^\top $ have a joint bivariate normal distribution $ Z \sim N\left( \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 2 \end{array}\right) , \left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & a\\ a & 3 \end{array}\right) \right) $ and calculated the only missing parameter, the covariance $a$ of the two random variables.

Now, [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Two_normally_distributed_random_variables_need_not_be_jointly_bivariate_normal) says that this is not always true and brings a counter example. [Here](http://www.abload.de/img/am9kp6.png) is the image of the example's resulting plot.

My question: Under which conditions *are* they jointly normally distributed?

Comment: **Related**: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30159/2970

Comment: The condition is that *every* linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is normally distributed. The wikipedia page includes this characterization under the [Definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Definition) subsection.

Comment: Given $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(2,3)$ and that the random variables are jointly normal, _how_ did you calculate the covariance $a$?  There _must_ have been some other information provided to you that enabled you to calculate $a$ because given just that $X\sim N(0,1)$ and $Y \sim N(2,3)$ (whether jointly normal or not), $a$ can have _any_ value in $[\sqrt{3}, -\sqrt{3}]$.

Comment: Also of interest: [surprising characterizations of the Gaussian distribution](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364/)

Comment: Dilip, I didn't calculate $a$, and there normally is more information. I just made up a few quick numbers :)

Comment: cardinal: Thanks for your answer. How would I show that every linear combination is normally distributed? Would I calculate the density of $a + bX + cY$?

Comment: Alexx, that's a little tricky to do well, because linear combinations can be degenerate. The fastest, most elegant, rigorous demonstrations look at the cumulant generating function.

Comment: In addition to what cardinal and whuber say, I would say that when two variables have normal marginals and a normal copula, then they are a multivariate normal distribution. Other copulae could potentially descrie the distribution.