# When are $(X, Y)$ jointly normal given that both $X$ and $Y$ are normal?

Tags: normal-distribution

We know that $X$, $Y$ are normal does not guarantee $(X, Y)$ is jointly normal.  A typical example is: $X=Z$, and $Y=ZU$, where $Z$ standard normal, $P(U=1)=P(U=-1)=1/2$, and $Z, U$ are independent.

My question is: what would be a condition for $(X, Y)$ to be jointly normal given that both $X$, and $Y$ are normal?

Comment: Answers appear at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364. See, for instance, http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4373 and http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/24591 (the Herschel-Maxwell theorem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Linear combination of $X$ and $Y$ is still  normal would be a condition for $(X,Y)$ to be jointly normal. Actually, it is a characterization of bivariate normal and could be generalize to $\mathbb{R}^p$.

PS: The third link @whuber provided talks about the Herschel-Maxwell Theorem. And it seems to me that this can not serve as a characterization for general multivariate normal, but could serve as a characterization for standard multivariate normal.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation so it seems I can not comment directly in that link.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  I was confused about this too.  Prompted by your answer, I searched a bit and found a proof: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ananth/223Spr07/jointlygaussian.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends what you're trying to do. In many cases, the simplest approach is just to make $X$ and $Y$ jointly normal by construction. E.g., suppose that you have independent standard Gaussians $U$, $V$, $W$, and then you set
$$ X = a\,U + b\,V; \ Y = c\,U + d\,W. $$
In this case, it's easy to check that $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal.