# Normal distribution and independence

Tags: time-series, normal-distribution, autocorrelation, independence

I was reading about white noise and it stated:

> Although $\varepsilon_t$ & $y_t$ are serially uncorrelated, they are not necessarily serially independent, because they are not necessarily normally distributed. If in addition to being serially uncorrelated, $y$ is serially independent, then we say $y$ is independent white noise.

I cannot understand the link between the normal distribution and being serially independent. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: @Dilip The statement *is* correct, because it does not assert (or even imply) that uncorrelated normal variables are independent. It only relies on the fact that it is invalid to infer independence from lack of correlation in non-normal variates.  Arka, your question is addressed [in many threads here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=normal%20correlation%20independence). The one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364 appears to contain some explicit answers.

Comment: @whuber I don't think any of the answers to [the question you referred to ... q/4364/6633](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4364/6633)  or comments thereon have any relevance to Arka's question. Could you be more specific as to which answer or comment you are saying is an _explicit_ answer to Arka's question?

Comment: @Dilip http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4837 concerns the relationship between correlation and independence in Normal variables.

Comment: @whuber I am still not understanding how ""Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent random variables.  Then $\sum_{i=1}^n{a_i x_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n{b_i x_i}$ are independent, where $a_i b_i \ne 0$, if and only if $X_i$ [are] normally distributed." is an answer to the question being asked here (or indeed is even a true statement since with $a_i=b_i\neq 0$, it seems to be saying that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_iX_i$ is independent of _itself_ exactly when all the $X_i$ are normal). However, I bow to your superior knowledge and wisdom and accept your contention that it is exactly what the OP needs to know.

Comment: @Dilip This is not an issue that could be settled by any amount of "superior knowledge" or "wisdom," because I think we may be discussing different interpretations of the question.

Comment: If yt=e1+e2+e3+e4+........ (White noise) then even in a normal distribution, how can they be ever independent? I am sorry guys i am doing FRM and am quite novice to stats.

Answer (score 2):

**My** interpretation of the (slightly paraphrased) statement that the OP is reading, *viz.*

> "If $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of (serially) *uncorrelated* random variables, then $\{Y_n\}$ is not necessarily a sequence of *independent* random variables, **because** (emphasis added) they are not necessarily normally distributed"

is that the author is asserting (quite correctly) that uncorrelated random variables need not be independent but the *reason* for this
failure of uncorrelatedness to imply independence is that we cannot assert that the uncorrelated random variables are normally distributed.
If the author is not *implying* that uncorrelated random variables that are normally distributed are independent random variables, then he is
certainly *begging* the reader to jump to that (false) conclusion,
by musing in the the subjunctive mood: "Gol dang it, if only those pesky
$Y_n$'s were normally distributed in addition to being
uncorrelated, then we could take those
uncorrelated (and normal) $Y_n$'s to be *independent* random variables
and avoid a lot of headaches."   However, Moderator @whuber has stated
(in a comment on the main question) that he does not interpret that
sentence that way, and that the
statement quoted by the OP is perfectly accurate.

In my opinion, the second sentence quoted by the OP.

> If in addition to being serially uncorrelated, the $\{Y_n\}$ are serially independent, then we say $\{Y_n\}$ is independent white noise.

also incorrect. Independent
random variables are *always* uncorrelated and it is unnecessary
to start with uncorrelated random variables and then impose the
additional constraint that they are independent random variables.
Furthermore, if by *serially independent* it is meant that
for all $n\neq m$, $Y_m$ and $Y_n$ are independent random variables
(that is, only *pairwise* independence is required), then I disagree
vehemently with the assertion that $\{Y_n\}$ is a *white* noise process.
For a random process to be called a white noise process, the
random variables need to be *mutually* independent, not just
pairwise independent, and most people, upon encountering the
phrase *white noise process*, are likely to
assume that the the random variables
constituting the white noise process also are zero-mean random variables with common *finite* variance $\sigma^2$. This property of the $Y_n$'s
is nowhere mentioned in the paragraph fragment quoted by the OP.

---

Finally, turning to the OP's complaint

> I cannot understand the link between the normal distribution and being serially independent

I say that it is a red herring. Uncorrelated (marginally)
normal random variables are not necessarily independent
random variables while uncorrelated **jointly** normal random
random variables are always independent random variables.

> It is *not* true that if $\{Y_n\}$ is a sequence of *normally* distributed random variables that happen to be uncorrelated, then the random variables are independent.

A standard counterexample begins with $X \sim N(0,1)$ and an independent random
variable $Z$ that takes on values $+1$ and $-1$ with equal probability.
Then $Y = XZ$ is also a standard normal random variable since
\begin{align}P\{Y \leq x\} &= P\{X \leq x\mid Z=+1\}P\{Z=+1\}
+ P\{X \geq -x\mid Z=-1\}P\{Z=-1\}\\
&= \frac 12 \Phi(x) + \frac 12 (1 - \Phi(-x))\\
&= \Phi(x).
\end{align}
Also,
$\quad\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]= E[X^2Z]=E[X^2]E[Z]=0$
showing that $X$ and $Y$ are
are *uncorrelated* random variables. But $X$ and $Y$, although they are
uncorrelated *normal*
random variables, are *not* independent random variables but instead
very much **dependent** random variables since given that $X=x$, $Y$ takes on values $\pm x$ with equal probability $\frac 12$.

Now, with $\{Z_n\}$ being a sequence
of *independent* random variables with the same distribution as $Z$ (and all independent of $X$ also), set
$Y_n = XZ_n$. It follows from our construction that $Y_n \sim N(0,1)$.
But,
$$E[Y_nY_{m}] = E[X^2Z_nZ_m] = E[X^2]E[Z_n]E[Z_m] = 0~\text{provided that} ~ n \neq m.$$
Thus, the $\{Y_n\}$ are uncorrelated and normal.
But they are *not* independent because if we know that $Y_m = y$, then we know that
$Y_n$ is necessarily either $y$ or $-y$.

Normal random variables need not  be *jointly* normal
random variables and it is only in the case of
*joint* normality that one can assert that uncorrelated (jointly)
normal random variables are independent.

Comment: +1 Although I did read the question differently, you have done a great job of explaining--and justifying--how you read it and of raising (and answering) the attendant questions.  I am sorry I overlooked your answer until now.