# Definition of Gaussian process

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process, multivariate-normal-distribution

Definition of a GP: a stochastic process $\{X_t, t\in T\}$ such that for every finite set of realization times $t_1, \dots, t_k \in T$, the joint $(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \dots, X_{t_k})$ is a multivariate Gaussian random variable.

I am wondering why we don't simply define a GP to be $\{X_t, t\in T\}$ such that for every $t$, $X_t$ is a single-variate Gaussian variable. If this were the case, then $X_t$ would satisfy the above definition (since a joint distribution of Gaussians is a multivariate Gaussian).

I'm guessing this second definition is broader than the true definition. Are there any processes $X_t$ that satisfy the definition I suggested but isn't an actual GP?

Thanks.

Comment: Re "a joint distribution of Gaussians is a multivariate Gaussian:" please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/30205/919.

Comment: Dang, that is a major counterargument, thank you! So it seems that a joint is Gaussian if the marginals are independent and gaussian. But that would only form a joint Gaussian with 0 covariances (i.e. that condition is sufficient but not necessary), right? Do you know what requirements would allow a set of gaussians to give a joint Gaussian with nonzero covariances?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4364.  Note that a joint Gaussian with nonzero covariances is *always* a linear transformation of a vector of independent Gaussian variables.

Comment: Can you clarify which part to look at?

Comment: All of the answers!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is possible to construct processes which are *marginally* normally distributed but not jointly normally distributed.

Take for example two variables that are not jointly normal distributed:
$$
X\sim N(0,1)\\
Y=|U|\cdot \text{sgn}(X), \quad U\sim N(0,1)
$$
and construct the stochastic process
$$
X_t=\begin{cases}
X \quad \text{if } t<1\\
Y \quad \text{if } t\geq 1
\end{cases}
$$

The variable $X_t$ is gaussian distributed for any $t$ but $(X_{0.5},X_2)$ is not gaussian distributed.

Comment: A nice example, (+1) !

Answer (score 3):

One of the most important features of GPs is the relationship between its output values, which is characterized by a kernel function $k(x,y) = \mathrm{Cov}(f(x),f(y))$.

If you define $f(x)$ only through marginals as $f(x) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu(x), \sigma(x))$, you do not define any relationship between $f(x), f(y)$ for $x\neq y$.

Comment: I see -- but whether or not we know the covariance has no effect on the definition of a GP. (All we know is that the joint is gaussian distributed, but no requirement on knowing the covariance matrix).

Answer (score 1):

For my reference and anyone else who might want it:

The best general answer results from [whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/919/whuber)'s [referred post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d/30205#30205), showing that Gaussian marginals do not generally combine to form a Gaussian joint. This shows that the answer to my posed question is **no, in general** (not just if variables are discontinuous, as demonstrated by svendvn).

The case where marginal Gaussians *do* form a Gaussian joint is when the variables are independent or are independent under some linear transformation: as whuber mentioned, any multivariate Gaussian (MVG) is equivalent under linear transformation to a MVG with zero covariances (*see below for explanation).

Another characterization is that the collection of rvs $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is jointly Gaussian iff for any $a_1, \dots, a_n$, the linear combination $\sum_i a_i X_i$ is Gaussian (see [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eananth/223Spr07/jointlygaussian.pdf)).

*If we have a multivariate $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, then a linear transformation $A$ gives $AX \sim \mathcal{N}(A\mu, A\Sigma A^\top)$. Since any covariance matrix $C$ is symmetric, it has the diagonalization $C = Q\Lambda Q^\top$ where $\Lambda$ is diagonal and $Q$ is an orthogonal transformation. This means that our $X$ can be transformed orthogonally to a coordinate system where it is a joint distribution of independent Gaussian marginals.

So in summary, it is necessary to define a GP as having joint Gaussian rather than joint marginals, and an alternate definition along this second route would be require an additional requirement of independence, i.e. "a stochastic process $X_t$ is a GP if for every $t$, $X_t$ is Gaussian distributed *and* every linear combination of a subset $(X_{t_1}, \dots, X_{t_n})$ is Gaussian.

Note: I'm still not sure how to prove that a set of variables is independent under some linear transformation

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "discontinuous" in relation to the example in my answer. Both the X and Y are continuous random variables and (X,Y) is a continuous random vector. Perhaps you are thinking about the density function of (X,Y) or perhaps X_t as a function of t? neither of those are continuous.