# Test for bivariate normality assumption

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption, bivariate

Assume two time series $X_1$ and $X_2$, where $X_i=(x_{i,1},...,x_{i,T})$. How can we test the assumption of bivariate normality for these time series? (Assume **each** of the time series are stationary and normally distributed).

Comment: did you try $\chi^2$ test?

Comment: Would you elaborate? @Aksakal

Comment: That what is bivariate normal, the  joint error term?

Comment: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/bivariate-normal-distribution @Dave

Comment: That each of the time series are normally distributed does not imply bivariate normality. Do you want to test the former or the latter?

Comment: Indeed. I want to test the bivariate normality assumption. @RichardHardy

Comment: A standard approach is to test the univariate Normality of linear combinations of the variables, according to [this characterization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/4373/919).  In almost any practical application, though, you shouldn't be formally testing: you should be *characterizing* the extent to which the data conform to any bivariate normality condition that might be needed to analyze them.  That would start with scatterplots, examination of bivariate outliers, etc.

Comment: @whuber Not sure if I'm following. For instance, how would you check the jointly normal with a scatterplot?

Comment: *Look at it.* The point is that certain behaviors, such as heavy tail behavior, strong skewness in some direction, tied values, etc. are likely to be what matters in your analysis.  It will be rare for any analysis to require such perfect conformance with bivariate normality that you can't determine compliance from a good scatterplot. Given that your time series already are Gaussian processes, it's going to be extremely difficult (in practice--there are theoretical exceptions) to depart from bivariate normality anyway.

Comment: Just to confirm that I understand this correctly; essentially do a QQ plot with x-axis showing $X_1$ and y-axis $X_2$? @whuber

Comment: That wouldn't do it: a QQ plot destroys the natural pairing among the variables.  Just plot $(X_1,X_2).$  Add some kind of smoother, such as a 2D KDE, to get a sense of the overall contours of density.

Comment: Is there a reason that you care about the time series themselves instead of, say, the (bivariate) error term? Any recommendation for a test or examination for normality is unhelpful is you test or examine the wrong numbers.

Comment: @Dave my goal is to construct a correlation coefficient confidence interval and I want to check if they are bivariate normal. Does that make sense?