# Characterization of normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, sample

How can one prove that the random sample is normally distributed if the sample mean and sample variance are independent?

Comment: I believe this issue was addressed here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/distributions-other-than-the-normal-where-mean-and-variance-are-independent